# TypeScript: Incorrect type inference in Promise.all

Tags: typescript

Please see this code (TypeScript 3.8.3) ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCquQb2QawgTwC5kBnMKUAc2QF8BuAKAYBsIxkAHARgAVieoAewC2wEhAA86ZAB9kAN0HAAJgD5GrdhwBMfZAJFjJ6dUwAUcEvhAJkZgJTIAvKqwNkyBIJBlkAbW4AGk5tAF1nZDgAdzhgdgNRcQA6OGZmMwDeYJ0eUPtGDwB6QuQAQQBhVABVUoAZd2Riz29fbmJFFVk0VAamrx8tbXalZS70XpKAWmmZieQAUQANHnnK+YAROf7WrmHOuXGiku3B4nGafKYGIA)):

```js
interface TT { key: string };

let p1P: Promise<TT | void>;
let p2P: Promise<TT>;

(async () => {
  const [p1, p2] = await Promise.all([p1P, p2P]);
  // EXPECTED TYPES OF p1 and p2
  // const p1: void | TT
  // const p2: TT

  // ACTUAL TYPES
  // const p1: void | TT
  // const p2: void | TT

});
```

Why the `void` type is also adding to the `p2` variable after `await`?

Comment: Good news for guys seeing this question in late 2021, typing of each array item in Promise.all() is currently supported (TypeScript 4.5.4) the awaited result will be a tuple, please check playground link in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the array passed to `Promise.all` isn't being typed explicitly, it's inferred to be a union of all its value types:

```
const arr = [p1P, p2P];
// is interpreted by Typescript as:
// const arr: Promise<void | TT>[]

// This is usually useful because it allows you to modify the array, eg:
// arr.push(p1P);
```

If you want to indicate that the indicies of the array contain *only* the value at currently at that index, use `as const`, and the array items' type won't be widened, so the resolve values will be typed as expected:

```
const [p1, p2] = await Promise.all([p1P, p2P] as const);
```

[image]

Comment: Got it. Worked in my editor. But the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=59&pln=7&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCquQb2QawgTwC5kBnMKUAc2QF8BuAKAYBsIxkAHARgAVieoAewC2wEhAA86ZAB9kADnkA+Rq3YcATH2QCRYyehVMAFHBL4QCZMYCUyALxKsDZMgSCQZZAG1uAGk4NAF0HZDgAdzhgdl1RcQA6OGZmY19eAM0eELM3DzIbRhoCpgYgA) still makes the wrong assertion, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it works on my end in VSCode with 3.8.3, but for some reason, the playground looks to be interpreting it differently despite having the exact same config... strange.